# how to convert mutiple row inputs to bootstrap row inputs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

how can i place multiple inputs into a single `row` having `responsive` nature

I'm facing very difficult to place all `inputs` into a single `row` only 3 I'm able to place

**I wanted to convert the below snippet into bootstrap so that I will be responsive:**

here codepen:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpbjKL

**html:**

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
    <label for="name">Company Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" value="" name="name" style="width:200px">
  </div>

  <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
    <label for="email">GST Number</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email">
  </div>

 <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
    <label for="email">Branch Address</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email" style="width:300px">
  </div>

<div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
    <label for="email">Tin Number</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email" style="width:200px">
  </div>

  <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
    <label for="email">pin code</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email" style="width:100px">
  </div>

<div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
    <label for="email">Date</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email" style="width:100px">
  </div>

<div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
    <label for="email">code</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email" style="width:100px">
  </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
input, label {
    display:block;
}
```

**Question**: how to convert above codepen output to bootstrap row,col-*

Answer (score 1):

use this class `col-md-auto` to make width auto and `d-inline-block` to display column inline block (bootstrap 4)

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-auto col-lg-auto d-inline-block">
    <label for="name">Company Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" value="" name="name" style="width:200px">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-auto col-lg-auto d-inline-block">
    <label for="email">GST Number</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email">
  </div>

 <div class="col-md-auto col-lg-auto d-inline-block" style="">
    <label for="email">Branch Address</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email" style="width:300px">
  </div>

<div class="col-md-auto col-lg-auto d-inline-block" style="">
    <label for="email">Tin Number</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email" style="width:200px">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-auto col-lg-auto d-inline-block" style="">
    <label for="email">pin code</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email" style="width:100px">
  </div>

<div class="col-md-auto col-lg-auto d-inline-block" style="">
    <label for="email">Date</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email" style="width:100px">
  </div>

<div class="col-md-auto col-lg-auto d-inline-block" style="">
    <label for="email">code</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email" style="width:100px">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can see the example below,this may satisfy your need. Also,you can set the col-x-x property to place more that 3 input in one row.

[row-col example](http://%20https://v3.bootcss.com/components/#input-groups-buttons)